# mipsel-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl, openwrt

I am using white Russian 0.9 on my linksyswrt54g router and now I am building a package for it. I am using the specified SDK for it. But this SDK is a stripped down version so it does not contain libcurl or curl library. I am getting the below error when i run the make V=99 command in the SDK folder:

> > > > error<<<<< mipsel-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl

I searched through the internet but couldn't find the libcurl or curl library that can be added to the usr/lib folder in staging_dir_mipsel directory. All I get is the .ipk file which I have already installed on router.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download **libcurl** from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.36.0.tar.gz),put libcurl to your SDK and cross compile it.

Comment: where your ld is going to find libcurl??

Comment: i need libcurl.a or libcurl.so file..
it looks into the staging-dir-mipsel/lib/ directory

Comment: can you provide me the .a and .so file for libcurl

Comment: Are you able to cross compile libcurl?

Comment: You should able to get libcurl precompiled here ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/sourceforge/k/ke/kernelloader/Sony%20Linux%20Toolkit/Package%20Update%20Files/cfyc/curl-7.9.8-1.mipsel.rpm

Comment: IGNORE ABOVE COMMENT,
that worked but gives an list of errors saying,
mipsel-linux-uclibc/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `strcpy@GLIBC_2.0'
undefined reference to `inet_addr@GLIBC_2.0'
undefined reference to `dlclose@GLIBC_2.0'
AND MANY MORE

Comment: I think my libcurl.so and libcurl.so.2.0.2 are not compatible with GLIBC_2.0, So can you provide me the libcurl.so.6. I think this is compatible with GLIBC_2.0

Comment: yes but now it shows error saying libcurl.so needs libc.so.6 and libld.so.2 and some errors like undefined reference to `abort@GLIBC_2.0'